# Checking all check boxes when main check box is clicked

Tags: jquery

Yesterday i was giving an answer to one of the stackoverflow question that `How to check/uncheck all checkboxes based on the selection of one checkbox` and i came up with this solution. But the problem is it only works once but it will not work if you click it twice. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xYAfj/1/)

```
$('#allcb').click(function(){
    if ($('#allcb').is(':checked'))
    {
      $('.chk').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('checked', true);
      });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.chk').each(function(){
           $(this).attr('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

I found this code which works fine according to the requirements 
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/4tss8/)

**So what is wrong with my approach? Either it should not work at all. If it works once why its not works twice?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [.prop() vs .attr()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)

Comment: Note if you want this to work correctly you have to put an event handler on .chk click, because currently if you uncheck one of the "slaves" checkboxes , the "master" checkbox will remain checked , same if you check all the  "slaves" checkboxes manually the master will remain unchecked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason it only works once is because you should have used `prop()`, not `attr()`.

`prop()` changes the property, as in `element.checked`, while `attr()` changes the attribute, as in `<input type="radio" checked="checked" />`, and changing the attribute does not change the property, which is essentially what you want, as changing the attribute will only work once because the next time the property is checked it comes back the opposite of the attribute.

See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) for an overview of the difference between prop and attr.

```
$('#allcb').click(function(){
    if ($('#allcb').is(':checked'))
    {
      $('.chk').each(function(){
        $(this).prop('checked', true);
      });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.chk').each(function(){
           $(this).prop('checked', false);
        });
    }
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYAfj/12/)

As a sidenote, that code can be summed up as :

```
$('#allcb').on('click', function(){
    $('.chk').prop('checked', this.checked);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/xYAfj/15/)

Comment: Your edited answer makes more sense to me. Thanks for the explanation.